# не работает плагин owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Всем здравствуйте! Нужна помощь. Есть модальное окно (#pop-up), которое появляется при клике на кнопку. И есть каталог с товарами (только картинки и название товара). Идея такова: нажимаешь на область около картинки товара, появляется модальное окно с его описанием. Я хочу, чтобы была возможность перелистывания описания товаров (т.е. когда появилось модальное окно, чтобы было стрелки переключения товаров и чтобы, когда кликаешь на любой див с картинкой товара, было понятно, какую информацию показывать).

```
<div id="pop-up">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme slide-two">
<div class="prod">
        <span class="product-title">Хлебцы острые с перцем</span>
        <div class="product-description">
            <span class="product-benefit">
    Мы разработали для Вас «Хлебцы Острые» с перцем, которые используют свойство перца стимулировать выработку эндорфинов – «гормонов счастья», повышающих общий уровень иммунитета человека!
            </span>
        <span class="composition">Состав: пшеница, паприка, перец красный, кориандр, морская соль.</span>
        <span class="nutritional-value">Пищевая ценность на 100 г: белки – 12,0 г; жиры – 1,5 г; углеводы – 72,0 г.
Энергетическая ценность в 100 г – 352 Ккал.</span>
        <span class="product-weight">Вес нетто: 65 г.</span>
        <span class="expiry-date">Срок годности: 9 мес.</span>
    </div>
        <div class="img-opis">
            <img src="assets/products/1.png" class="image-opis">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prod">
        <span class="product-title">Хлебцы зерновые с тмином</span>
        <div class="product-description">
            <span class="product-benefit">  
    Хлебцы Зерновые с тмином имеют сбалансированный вкус. Не забывайте о пользе витаминов и минеральных веществ так необходимых вашему организму. Мы используем только натуральные ингредиенты, поэтому наша продукция подходит для ежедневного употребления.
            </span>
        <span class="composition">Состав: пшеница, хлопья овсяные, крупа кукурузная, тмин, морская соль.</span>
        <span class="nutritional-value">Пищевая ценность на 100 г: белки – 14,0 г; жиры – 4,0 г; углеводы – 74,0 г.
Энергетическая ценность в 100 г – 405 Ккал.</span>
        <span class="product-weight">Вес нетто: 65 г.</span>
        <span class="expiry-date">Срок годности: 9 мес.</span>
    </div>
        <div class="img-opis">
            <img src="assets/products/2.jpg" class="image-opis">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
#pop-up {
    display: none;
    width:80%;
    height: 70%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:20%;
    left: 15%;
    padding: 27px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
.prod {
  font-size:24px;
  display: flex;
}
.product-description {
  flex:2;
}
.product-title {
  align-self:center;
  flex:1;
}
.img-opis {
  flex:1;
}
.image-opis {
    height: 400px;
}
```

---

```
$('.item-box').click(function () { 
    $('#pop-up').show();
    $(".slide-two").owlCarousel({
        item:1,
        nav:true,   
    });
    $("#all").css({"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)", "z-index":15000});
    $("#pop-up").css("z-index",3000000);
});
```

---

где item-box - блок с картинкой и названием товара.
Если убрать div class="owl-carousel owl-theme slide-two" и описание второго товара,то описание отображается корректно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда добавляю див со слайдером и описание второго товара, вид такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Карусель не работает. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, в чем проблема??

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в .prod ширину в 100%, должно помочь.

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло((

Comment: Поменяй библиотеку на flickity. Она удобнее как по мне

Comment: Поменяла :) Сразу слайдеры начала работать! Спасибо!
Только вот отображается инфа не так, как следует( Без библиотеки было всё ок

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при клике на блок с товаром, было понятно описание какого именно товара показывать, а не первого, как это  реализовано сейчас.
`$('.item-box').click(function () { 
 $('#pop-up').show();
 $("#pop-up").css("z-index",3000000);
       $('.main-gallery').flickity({
       cellAlign: 'left',
            contain: true,
            wrapAround: true,
});
  $("#all").css({"background":"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)", "z-index":15000}); 
});`
где #pop-up - модальное окно с инфой о товаре, .item-box - блок с товаром

Comment: Я думаю, что стоит хранить инфу о товаре в атрибутах .item-box  или иметь уникальные pop-up под каждый товар

Comment: а если товаров тысячи, вряд ли тогда есть смысл делать столько pop-up..

Comment: Можно для хранения использовать data-атрибут - если не много позиций

А для "тысяч" товаров нужно будет по клику определять ID товара, стучаться AJAXом в БД и подтягивать недостающие атрибуты

Comment: Я поняла. Получается каждому div class= item-box присваивает атрибут data-. А вот как это на js написать, не знаю.

Comment: Поиск в гугле. https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=WQKMW4W1EJOSmgXB-YDwAQ&q=data+jquery&oq=data+&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.35i39k1j0i67k1l3j0l6.1223.1223.0.2466.1.1.0.0.0.0.70.70.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.69....0.tF-1TLWi18A Статья на хабре. 
https://habr.com/post/139210/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь